# ¿Como cargar un listview dentro de otro listview?

Tags: android

Buen día.

Tengo un listView en el cual debo cargar dentro de el mismo otro listado de datos, es decir en cada item del listView hay un botón, cuando se presiona ese botón me debería traer una lista de datos, pero no he encontrado la manera de solucionar esta situación.

De antemano gracias.

Comment: tal vez necesites un spinner en lugar de otro listview dentro https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html?hl=es-419

Comment: @devjav te recomiendo probar lo que indico en mi respuesta, si deseas un listview dentro de otro tendrias que validar cuando permitir o no el scroll, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Un `ListView` tiene una lista de elementos los cuales pueden visualizarse mediante scroll, si agregas dentro otro elemento que tiene su propio scroll sería un poco complicado usarlo y no sería algo recomendable.

> Tengo un listView en el cual debo cargar dentro de el mismo otro
>   listado de datos, es decir en cada item del listView hay un botón,
>   cuando se presiona ese botón me debería traer una lista de datos

Creo que lo recomendable aquí es que ese botón genere un listado pero dentro de un `LinearLayout` y no otro `listView`, por ejemplo el botón dentro del ListView puede generar un linear layout con sus elementos en forma de lista:

```
LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_root);
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
linearLayout.addView(myTextView1);
linearLayout.addView(myTextView2);
linearLayout.addView(myTextView3);
linearLayout.addView(myTextView4);
linearLayout.addView(myTextView5);
...
...
root.addView(linearLayout);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Elenasys, soluciono mi problema pero cuando cargo por ejemplo dos item al dar click al botón cargan perfecto, pero al bajar el scroll hacia abajo y volver, ya no están y debo volver a dar click al botón para ver los items ¿A que se debe esta situación?

Comment: En el método getView() realiza una validación para que no cargué de nuevo el convertView: public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    if( convertView == null ){
        //inflar de nuevo :

     }

Comment: Use tu sugerencia pero aun me sigue pasando